# Android user interface coding error

Tags: java, android, user-interface

So, I've had problems with adding buttons through coding. This is the error message I get from logcat when I get to the activity which is supposed to do the things:

```
09-30 09:36:51.591: E/AndroidRuntime(14956): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gameproj/com.example.gameproj.MapMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here's the code which seems to be relevant:

```
        map = new Button[loadedMap.getX()][loadedMap.getY()];
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapything);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams coord;
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++){
                map[i][j] = new Button(this);
                coord = new LayoutParams(16*i, 75+16*j);
                map[i][j].setLayoutParams(coord);
                map[i][j].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                layout.addView(map[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

From what I could debug, the error is around the layout.addView(map[i][j]) line, but I've been unable to find out how to get it to work.

Edit: I'm not sure what else to put, but I'll go ahead and put the xml file to see if it'll make something more clear

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapything"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="toCharacter"
        android:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Map"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post some more codes...

Comment: I've added some more codes, but I'm not sure what else I would need to add.

Answer (score 2):

I think that problem in this line `for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; i++)` try to replace it with `for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++)`.

Comment: I think that would have been a problem, so thanks. Though I'm still getting the NullPointerException errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your variables are declared.  But Java is very critical about the sizes of arrays.  So if you have an array set to [12] (or something), your index cannot go higher than 11 (12 elements).  Otherwise you get a null pointer exception.

Check the rest of your log.  It will tell you which array is not sized properly.